# How to do self join and create a new column in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, self-join

I created a table from a huge database after running multiple queries like the following is the sample:

```
communication_day | comid | person_id | area_id | w_id  
20-MAR-17 03:45 | 21 | xyz1 | y123 | S1
20-MAR-17 07:45 | 21 | xyz1 | y142 | S2
14-MAR-17 07:45 | 41 | xyz1 | y153 | S1
14-MAR-17 09:00 | 41 | xyz1 | y123 | S3
30-MAR-17 09:00 | 88 | abc1 | y180 | D1
30-MAR-17 11:00 | 88 | abc1 | y181 | D2
```

Basically, a person (represented by `person_id`) comes in and requests change in its area id, this could be done be a person multiple times. Each time a person requests this, he is given a `comid`. So, like in the above example `person_id` = `xyz1` first requests a change from `y153` to `y123` and then on 20th march, requests a change from `y123` to `y142`.

I want to create a new column in this table called `old_w_id` such that for each change request (each comid) it has that old value in it. Eg for the above sample:

```
old_w_id
S1
S1
S1
S1
D1
D1
```

Cases where request came in for that comid, the old_w_id can have the same value only. Only where the change request has taken effect, old_w_id should have the previous value.

Any idea how do I do that?? Thanks in advance!!

UPDATE: Each comid might not necessarily have 2 rows i.e, a person might have requested the change but it might not have been acknowledged yet (that gives just one row for that comid at this time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course I can explain. `partition by` clause tells analytic function to do calculation partitioned by column you specified, in our case it's the `person_id`, otherwise `lag` function will work for all rows through your returned row set. And also I'll remove default value for first record, I'll change `lag(w_id, 1, w_id)` to `lag(w_id, 1)` it's more correct to show `null`, because there is no lag `w_id` for it. Something like this.

```
with my_table as
 (

  select to_date('20-MAR-17 03:45', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI',
                   'nls_date_language=english') as communication_day, 21 as comid,
          'xyz1' as person_id, 'y123' as area_id, 'S1' w_id
    from dual
  union all

  select to_date('20-MAR-17 03:45', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI',
                   'nls_date_language=english') as communication_day, 21 as comid,
          'xyz1' as person_id, 'y142' as area_id, 'S2' w_id
    from dual
  union all
  select to_date('14-MAR-17 07:45', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI',
                   'nls_date_language=english') as communication_day, 41 as comid,
          'xyz1' as person_id, 'y153' as area_id, 'S1' w_id
    from dual
  union all
  select to_date('14-MAR-17 09:00', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI',
                   'nls_date_language=english') as communication_day, 41 as comid,
          'xyz1' as person_id, 'y123' as area_id, 'S3' w_id
    from dual
  union all
  select to_date('30-MAR-17 09:05', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI',
                   'nls_date_language=english') as communication_day, 88 as comid,
          'abc1' as person_id, 'y180' as area_id, 'D1' w_id
    from dual
  union all
  select to_date('30-MAR-17 11:00', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI',
                   'nls_date_language=english') as communication_day, 88 as comid,
          'abc1' as person_id, 'y181' as area_id, 'D2' w_id
    from dual)

select t.*,
       lag(w_id, 1) over(partition by person_id, comid order by communication_day) as old_w_id
  from my_table t
```

out put will be

```
    COMMUNICATION_DAY   COMID   PERSON_ID   AREA_ID W_ID    OLD_W_ID
1   30/03/17 09:05:00   88      abc1        y180    D1  
2   30/03/17 11:00:00   88      abc1        y181    D2      D1
3   14/03/17 07:45:00   41      xyz1        y153    S1  
4   14/03/17 09:00:00   41      xyz1        y123    S3      S1
5   20/03/17 03:45:00   21      xyz1        y123    S1      
6   20/03/17 03:45:00   21      xyz1        y142    S2      S1
```

Comment: Everything here seems fine except row 5 in the output, which shows S3 as the old_w_id, however row 5 has a new comid, that means a new request came, so it should have old_w_id as null. Is it possible to partition by person_id and comid both? (Sorry, I haven't used partition before)

Comment: I edited query, now it partitions by two fields first of all, `person_id`, and then for each person_id by `comid`, sorry edited from mobile, can't correct output, right now.